# Showing explore posts in a more sophisticated way

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

In my last post someone helped me to show my explore posts and it was very helpful. But I wanna show it in a different way.

When I show my news feed or my profile posts and I reach the bottom, it loads more posts. With my previous code, it just loaded all of them and that's a problem because if there a thousand posts they'll all be loaded at once and I don't want that issue. So I wanna set it up in a way that will load more posts as I get to the bottom. It works for my news feed and profile posts but not the explore posts. It immediately gives me the else statement. it's kind of long but I'm guessing the problem is somewhere at the top of method.

```
public function loadExplorePosts($data, $limit) {

$page = $data['page']; 
$userLoggedIn = $this->user_obj->getUsername();

if($page == 1) 
    $start = 0;
else 
    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;

$str = ""; //String to return 

$explore_image = $this->con->prepare('SELECT id, body, added_by, date_added, likes, image FROM posts ORDER BY RAND()');
$explore_image->execute();
// $explore_image->store_result();
//$explore_image->bind_result($id, $body, $added_by, $date_added, $likes, $image);
$explore_image_result = $explore_image->get_result();

    if ($explore_image_result->num_rows > 0) {

    $num_iterations = 0; //Number of results checked (not necasserily posted)
    $count = 1;

    while ($row = $explore_image_result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $id = $row['id'];
        $body = $row['body'];
        $added_by = $row['added_by'];
        $date_time = $row['date_added'];
        $imagePath = $row['image'];

    if ($userLoggedIn != $added_by) {

        //Check if user who posted, has their account closed
        $added_by_obj = new User($this->con, $added_by);
        if($added_by_obj->isClosed()) {
            continue;
        }

        $user_logged_obj = new User($this->con, $userLoggedIn);
        if($user_logged_obj->isFriend($added_by)){

            if($num_iterations++ < $start)
                continue; 

            //Once 10 posts have been loaded, break
            if($count > $limit) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                $count++;
            }

            if($userLoggedIn == $added_by)
                $delete_button = "<button class='delete_button btn-danger' id='post$id'>X</button>";
            else 
                $delete_button = "";

            $user_details_query = $this->con->prepare('SELECT first_name, last_name, profile_pic FROM users WHERE username = ?');
            $user_details_query->bind_param("s", $added_by);
            $user_details_query->execute();
            $user_details_query_result = $user_details_query->get_result();

            while ($row = $user_details_query_result->fetch_assoc()) {

                $first_name = $row['first_name'];
                $last_name = $row['last_name'];
                $profile_pic = $row['profile_pic'];
            }

            ?>
            <script> 
                function toggle<?php echo $id; ?>(event){
                        
                    var target = $(event.target);
                 
                    if (!target.is('a') && !target.is('button')) {
                        var element = document.getElementById("toggleComment<?php echo $id; ?>");
                 
                        if(element.style.display == "block")
                            element.style.display = "none";
                        else
                            element.style.display = "block";
                    }
                                                
                }

            </script>
            <?php

            $comments_check = $this->con->prepare('SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = ?');
            $comments_check->bind_param("i", $id);
            $comments_check->execute();
            $comments_check->store_result();
            $comments_check_num = $comments_check->num_rows;

            //Timeframe
            $date_time_now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $start_date = new DateTime($date_time); //Time of post
            $end_date = new DateTime($date_time_now); //Current time
            $interval = $start_date->diff($end_date); //Difference between dates 
            if($interval->y >= 1) {
                if($interval->y == 1)
                    $time_message = $interval->y . " yr"; //1 year ago
                else 
                    $time_message = $interval->y . " yrs"; //1+ year ago
            }
            else if ($interval->m >= 1) {
                if($interval->d == 0) {
                    $days = " ago";
                }
                else if($interval->d == 1) {
                    $days = $interval->d . "d";
                }
                else {
                    $days = $interval->d . "ds";
                }

                if($interval->m == 1) {
                    $time_message = $interval->m . "m ". $days;
                }
                else {
                    $time_message = $interval->m . "m ". $days;
                }

            }
            else if($interval->d >= 1) {
                if($interval->d == 1) {
                    $time_message = "Yesterday";
                }
                else {
                    $time_message = $interval->d . " days ago";
                }
            }
            else if($interval->h >= 1) {
                if($interval->h == 1) {
                    $time_message = $interval->h . "hr";
                }
                else {
                    $time_message = $interval->h . "hrs";
                }
            }
            else if($interval->i >= 1) {
                if($interval->i == 1) {
                    $time_message = $interval->i . "min";
                }
                else {
                    $time_message = $interval->i . " mins";
                }
            }
            else {
                if($interval->s < 30) {
                    $time_message = "Just now";
                }
                else {
                    $time_message = $interval->s . "sec";
                }
            }

            if($imagePath != "") {
                $imageDiv = "<div class='postedImage'>
                                <img src='$imagePath'>
                            </div>";
            }
            else {
                $imageDiv = "";
            }

            $str .= "<div class='status_post' onClick='javascript:toggle$id(event)'>
                        <div class='post_profile_pic'>
                            <img src='$profile_pic' width='50'>
                        </div>

                        <div class='posted_by' style='color:#ACACAC;'>
                            <a href='$added_by'> $first_name $last_name </a> $user_to &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$time_message
                            $delete_button
                        </div>
                        <div id='post_body'>
                            $body
                            <br>
                            $imageDiv
                            <br>
                            <br>
                        </div>

                        <div class='newsfeedPostOptions'>
                            Comments($comments_check_num)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <iframe src='like.php?post_id=$id' scrolling='no'></iframe>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class='post_comment' id='toggleComment$id' style='display:none;'>
                        <iframe src='comment_frame.php?post_id=$id' id='comment_iframe' frameborder='0'></iframe>
                    </div>
                    <hr>";
        }

        ?>
        
        <?php

    }
    } //End while loop

    if($count > $limit) 
        $str .= "<input type='hidden' class='nextPage' value='" . ($page + 1) . "'>
                    <input type='hidden' class='noMorePosts' value='false'>";
    else 
        $str .= "<input type='hidden' class='noMorePosts' value='true'><p style='text-align: centre;' class='noMorePostsText'><center> No more posts to show! </center></p><br><br>";
}

echo $str;
}
```

EDIT -----------

I just tried this and the if echo showed up so maybe it's the way I'm trying to output the results:

```
if ($explore_image_result > 0) {
    echo "Found";
} else {

    echo "not";
}
```

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Comment: @tadman what's the significance of the elephant in the room?

Comment: @tadman but I read that a framework isn't as flexible as doing it from scratch. And besides I wanna do it in pure plain php from scratch

Comment: @Strawberry Part pun, part PHP logo.

Comment: You may not need that flexibility. You just need to develop a web application. You don't need the flexibility to launch a car into the sun. Constraints will help you focus on building a good application. Flexibility without control is how you make a giant mess of things.